# Creating own input language for Windows 7 PC

Tags: windows-7, input

Is there a way to create my own input language in Windows 7? For example I switch from EN to, let's say for example RR, and then, when I press "A" on my keyboard, it inserts (Alt + 241) symbol, and so on. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). It is a small scripting language for windows that you can link with hotkeys. I use it myself to insert french accents using an US keyboard.
To do what you want the source code is simply:

```
a::send, ±
```

Save this to a file called `keyboard.ahk` for example and drag-n-drop it on `AutoHotKey.exe` to launch it. A system tray icon will appear with a white H over green. Right click it to close the program. After you can use the utility `Ahk2Exe` to package it as a stand-alone binary.

There is a UTF-8 compatible version called AutoHotKey_L if you need to insert really special characters.